# Is **Grab your passport and my hand** an imperative?

Tags: lyrics

In Taylor Swift's song [Blank Space](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/taylorswift/blankspace.html), I am wondering if the bolded line below is an imperative phrase or not:

> Nice to meet you
>
> Where you been?
>
> I could show you incredible things
>
> Magic, madness, heaven, sin
>
> Saw you there and I thought oh my god
>
> Look at that face, you look like my next mistake
>
> Love's a game, wanna play
>
> New money, suit and tie
>
> I can read you like a magazine
>
> Ain't it funny rumors fly
>
> And I know you heard about me
>
> So hey, let's be friends
>
> I'm dying to see how this one ends
>
> **Grab your passport and my hand**
>
> I could make the bad guys good for a weekend
>
> So it's gonna be forever
>
> Or it's gonna go down in flames
>
> You can tell me when it's over
>
> If the high was worth the pain
>
> Got a long list of ex-lovers
>
> They'll tell you I'm insane
>
> Cause you know I love the players
>
> And you love the game

Comment: Yes, *grab* is an imperative here.

Comment: What else do you think it might be?

Answer (score 2):

After looking up [Imperative Sentences on Grammar Monster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/imperative_sentence.htm) to confirm I would conclude that yes, "Grab your passport and my hand" is an imperative sentence.